keep getting TypeError: array.push is not a function when trying to push an object into an existing array with objects
I'm learning about localStorage and I'm trying to build a basic shopping cart function. The process is:

user clicks on "Add To Cart" button.
If localStorage("shoppingCart") doesn't exist, then localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", itemToAdd).
If localStorage("ShoppingCart) DOES exist (which for testing purposes, it does) then bring in the JSON string and parse it into an initialized array called updatedShoppingCart = [];
clear the localStorage,
push the itemToAdd object to the updatedShoppingCart array.
Then set the updatedShoppingCart array to local storage with localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(updatedShoppingCart)) for later usage in shopping process.

but I keep getting the TypeError: updatedShoppingCartArray.push is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.addToCart error on step #5.
Here's my code:
// simulate a product in the localStorage.
let prepTesting = {
   name: "Tshirt: Enter the Red Dragon",
   price: 3225,
   qty: 1
};

localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(prepTesting));


// Get values from product index.html page
let order_item_name = document.getElementById('order_item_name');
let order_item_price = document.getElementById('order_item_price');
let order_item_qty = document.getElementById('order_qty');

// initialize buttons
const btn_addToCart = document.getElementById('btn_addToCart');
const btn_clrLocalStorage = document.getElementById('btn_clrLocalStorage');

// set object with product order values
let itemToAdd = {
   name: order_item_name.dataset.name,
   price: parseInt(order_item_price.dataset.price),
   qty: parseInt(order_item_qty.value)
};

function clrLS(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   localStorage.clear();
   location.reload();
}

function addToCart(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   // assign localStorage("shoppingCart") to shoppingCart to check if it exists
   let shoppingCart = localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart");

   if (shoppingCart === null) {
      // push itemToAdd to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(itemToAdd));
   }else {
      // initialize array to insert localStorage array
      let updatedShoppingCartArray = [];

      // get and insert localStorage into updatedShoppingCartArray
      updatedShoppingCartArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));

      // clear localStorage for clean setting.
      localStorage.clear();

      // push itemToAdd into updatedShoppingCartArray
      // This is where I get the "updatedShoppingCartArray.push is not a function" error
      updatedShoppingCartArray.push(itemToAdd); 
      console.log(updatedShoppingCartArray);

      // set updatedShoppingCart to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(updatedShoppingCartArray));
   }
}

btn_addToCart.addEventListener('click', addToCart);
btn_clrLocalStorage.addEventListener('click', clrLS);

I believe my pseudo-code is correct and I can't figure out what the issue is with the error when running the script.
Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Seems obvious that the JSON in localStorage is not an array, probably an object

Looking closer, you store itemToAdd in localStorage which is indeed an object

even though it was stringifyied? does't it make it into a string?

JSON is always a string. I'm talking about the data type once it is parsed

The error updatedShoppingCartArray.push is not a function occurs because updatedShoppingCartArray is not an array. When you retrieve an item from localStorage, it's parsed as an object, not an array, since you originally stored an object. You need to ensure updatedShoppingCartArray is always an array before trying to push new items into it.
Explanation:
Check if shoppingCart exists: localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") returns null if the key doesn't exist.
If it doesn't exist: Initialize the shopping cart with an array containing itemToAdd.
If it exists: Parse it using JSON.parse(shoppingCart).
Check if the parsed result is an array using Array.isArray().
If it's not an array, convert it to an array containing the existing item.
Push the new item: Add the new item to the array and update localStorage.
This approach ensures that updatedShoppingCartArray is always an array before attempting to use push.
Here is revised version of your code :
function addToCart(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   // assign localStorage("shoppingCart") to shoppingCart to check if it exists
   let shoppingCart = localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart");

   if (shoppingCart === null) {
      // If no shopping cart exists, create one with the current item
      localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify([itemToAdd]));
   } else {
      // parse shoppingCart into an array
      let updatedShoppingCartArray = JSON.parse(shoppingCart);

      // Check if updatedShoppingCartArray is an array
      if (!Array.isArray(updatedShoppingCartArray)) {
         // If it's not an array, convert it to an array containing the existing item
         updatedShoppingCartArray = [updatedShoppingCartArray];
      }

      // push itemToAdd into updatedShoppingCartArray
      updatedShoppingCartArray.push(itemToAdd);
      console.log(updatedShoppingCartArray);

      // set updatedShoppingCart to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(updatedShoppingCartArray));
   }
}


Thank you for the feedback and input. I wasn't aware one could convert an object into an array and your response had helped me understand it better. The part I just couldn't get around is how to keep the localStorage in array form and everything I was researching into didn't explain it. Anyhow, thank you very much.

localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify([prepTesting]));

//...

if (shoppingCart === null) {
  // push itemToAdd to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify([itemToAdd]));
}

You need to put your initial item into an array.
At the moment, you are putting the initial object in as an object, not an array with a single object in it.
You have a couple of wrong assumptions in your code.
First, you are assuming that your object that you send to the localstorage will be stored as an array.
Localstorage is key value pairs. When you set an item in localstorage, you are storing a string (or number). You can use it to store objects, including arrays of objects by stringifying the object.
When you setItem and stringify your item, it is not an array. It is the object. When you parse it back out, you get an object, not an array.
So the first fix is to stringify an array with your object in it, and setItem that stringified array.
The second assumption you make is here:
 let updatedShoppingCartArray = [];

  // get and insert localStorage into updatedShoppingCartArray
  updatedShoppingCartArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));

This does not get and insert. What it does is replace the array reference with a reference to the parsed content of localStorage's shoppingCart key.
And from your earlier code, this is not an array - it is an object.
You would have detected this logic error if you had declared updatedShoppingCartArray as const. A const array can be mutated - you can add and remove elements - but you cannot reassign the variable name to point to a different object, which is what your code does.

but doesn't .push add the itemToAdd object to the end of the arrayShoppingCart array that already has the localStorage object?

I updated the answer to address your question.

oh! I took const as it can't change values once initiated and assigned. Thank you for clarifying this for me.
